# Mod_rewrite, $_GET does not pass along the variable

Tags: mod-rewrite, get

I'm trying to make

```
domain.com/notalone/viewpost/5/
```

act as

```
domain.com/notalone/viewpost.php?id=5
```

My current .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^notalone/viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$ /viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Currently, the page loads properly when you visit `/notalone/viewpost/5/` but **it does not pass `$_GET['id']`**

**Things I've Tried**:

- Adding `Options -Multiviews` ---> *Results in a 404*
- Using `Rewritebase /` ---> *No effect*
- `RewriteRule ^viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$ /viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA]` ---> *No effect*

Comment: There might be a challenge in combining `[QSA]` and `?id=$1`. You could use: `RewriteRule ^viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$ /viewpost.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}` without the QSA

Comment: If you hardcode the $1 to some string like 'blah' and does it come through?  It could be your $1 variable is not capturing what you think it is.

Comment: No luck. Here's a snippet of the server vars `["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(21) "/notalone/viewpost/5/" `

Comment: @EricLeschinski Changed it to `blah` and `5`, neither of which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. The problem was evidently an issue with my directories, because when I moved the website to it's own host (its own root directory instead of the notalone subdirectory), everything seemed to work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the pass-through flag, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^notalone/viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$ /viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,PT]
```

'PT' adjusts the internal URL so later handlers see the result of the mod_rewrite work, rather than the original URL.